# COUNTIFS based on multiple criteria across multiple columns on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet up on Google Sheets that I'm using to sort of keep a record of outgoing transport checking. This is the first page where the checklist is recorded:
[image: Page1]

Then I want to have a monthly summary of how many transport have been checked that month, how many transport in that month that had a non-compliance, as well as the number of non-compliance of that month, which looks like this:

[image]

So basically, in column C of this page, I want to count the number of transport which have a "NO" in their row from the first page.
And in column D, I want to count the amount of "NO" appeared within that month.

The only problem I face is that when I add the month as one of the criteria, the countif won't return any value. The date in column M is entered as 06/01/2020 (dd/MM/YYYY) if that has anything to with it.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Can be accessed here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8a-DSOeVPzO8yJqR5cjYMIJdWWcqpjgXljA4Dvxhw8/edit?usp=sharing